# Are sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6 still using sin_len and sin6_len?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, sockets

So, basically the title says it all. I've been porting my unix socket C code to Windows, and apparently those structures do not have sin_len or sin6_len in windows.

I'm using a union between sockaddr_storage, sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6 everywhere, and just using the correct member according to ss_family. It would make sense that the socket library could just deduce the size according to the family, so the length field would indeed be redundant.

If I comment out the code that sets the length field, everything still works on OSX and linux, but that may be just an illusion, so I decided to ask here.
Is that variable deprecated, somehow? Can I safely stop using it, and rely on the socket implementation to use the family variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sin_len field is not required by the POSIX specification.

Here's the relevant information from **Unix Network Programming - Vol 1. The Sockets Networking API, 3rd Edition**:

**3.2 Socket Address Structures**

> The length member, **sin_len**, was added with 4.3BSD-Reno, when support
> for the OSI protocols was added (Figure 1.15).  Before this release,
> the first member was **sin_family**, which was historically an unsigned
> short.  Not all vendors support a length field for socket address
> structures and the POSIX specification does not require this member.

Further Steven's provides the motivation behind the field:

> Having a length field simplifies the handling of variable-length socket address structures.
>
> Even if the length field is present, we need never set it and need never examine it, unless we are dealing with routing sockets (Chapter 18).  It is used within the kernel by the routines that deal with socket address structures from various protocol families (e.g, the routing table code).
>
> The four socket functions that pass a socket address structure from the process to the kernel, **bind, connect, sendto, and sendmsg**, all go through the **sockargs** function in a Berkeley-derived implementation (p. 452 of TCPv2).  This function copies the socket address structure from the process and explicitly sets its **sin_len** member to the size of the structure that was passed as an argument to these four functions.  The five socket functions that pass a socket address structure from the kernel to the process, **accept, recvfrom, recvmsg, getpeername, and getsockname**, all set the **sin_len** member before returning to the process.
>
> Unfortunately, there is normally no simple compile-time test to determine whether an implementation defines a length field for its socket address structures...We will see in Figure 3.4 that IPv6 implementations are required to define **SIN6_LEN** if the socket address structures have a length field.  Some IPv4 implementations provide the length field of the socket address structure to the application based on a compile-time option (e.g., **_SOCKADDR_LEN**).

You'll want to evaluate the usage of sin_len in your code.  If it's just initializing it to 0, you can remove the code.  If you're reading the value from the result of **accept, recvfrom, recvmsg, getpeername, or getsockname**, you'll unfortunately need some platform specific compile switches or switch to using the separate address length variable

Comment: Nah, like I said, I tried commenting the usage of that variable, and everything is still ok. I was just wondering if it was ok because I got lucky, or ok because it's still supposed to work without using that variable. I guess that answers it, then :)